# Terminate IMAP Node correctly if no results

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I am trying to exit the script if there are no emails that match our search criteria. If I don't do `imap.end()`, it never terminates. When I add the imap.end, I get an `ECONNRESET`. What's the proper way to exit out of IMAP early?

```
function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('[Gmail]/All Mail', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;

    const aDayAgo = moment().subtract(1,'d');
    imap.search([ ['SUBJECT', DPR_SUBJECT], ['SINCE', aDayAgo] ], function(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (results.length == 0){
        logging.log("No mail");
        db.disconnect();
        imap.end();
        return;
      }
      var f = imap.fetch(results, {
        bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
        struct: true
      });
      f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
        logging.verbose('Message #%d', seqno);

        msg.once('end', function() {
          logging.verbose(prefix + 'Finished');
        });
      });
      f.once('error', function(err) {
        logging.verbose('Fetch error: ' + err);
      });
      f.once('end', function() {
        logging.log('Done fetching all messages!');
        db.disconnect();
        imap.end();
      });
    });
  });
});

imap.once('error', function(err) {
  logging.error(err.stack);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  logging.verbose('Connection ended');
});

exports.checkForMail = () => {
  return imap.connect();
}
```